# This case only count the total loans; I want to calculate total loans and numbers but numbers didn't count

Tags: sql

```
WITH cTE AS
(
    SELECT
        COUNT(CASE WHEN days_delay > 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS number,
        COUNT(loan_id) AS total_loans
    FROM
        loan_aggregate
)
SELECT  
    number, total_loans, 
    (number / total_loans) AS default_rt 
FROM
    cTE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this expression, the `count()` is equivalent to `count(*)`, because both the `then` and `else` are not-`NULL`.  You can use either:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN days_delay>30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

or:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN days_delay>30 THEN 1 END)
```

My preference is the `SUM()` version.

Comment: but first it calculate the rate (number/total loans ) after i made it sum it give it with zero

Comment: @YoussefFahmy . . . Depending on the database you are using, it might be doing integer division.  That would be fixed using `number * 1.0 / total_loans`.